# Google Reader API - get subscribers

Tags: api, google-reader

Anyone know the http request in order to find the subscriber count for a subscription?
Something similar to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true must exist for subscribers, no?

Answer (score 4):

This is what Reader uses to fill in the data in the "show details" UI for a particular feeed:

http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/details?s=feed/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/&output=json&fetchTrends=false

Specifically, you'd want the "subscribers" property in the JSON output. The general format for the "s" parameter is feed/". Note that it requires authentication.

Comment: Do you know what `successfulCrawlTimeUsec` and `failedCrawlTimeUsec` means?

Comment: The times (in microseconds since the UNIX epoch) of the most recent successful and failed fetch of the feed from the server that hosts it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this same thing but from PUBLIC location so [i hacked together an API for everyones use](http://blog.cartercole.com/2010/06/google-reader-subscriber-statistics-api.html)... it returns as JSON or JSONP and i dont save any history of feeds that are looked up... but i do have logging to be able to ban abusive ip

Comment: i just updated it so if you pass output=xml it will send back XML response

Comment: Carter, great stuff, thank you. I'm currently using your API in a little utility I'm putting together.